# What is the difference between a Teacher & an Instructor?

Tags: teaching, terminology, etiquette

Although I could answer this question according to my class; **In general terms with all forms of martial arts how can we define the difference between them** ?

****What else i would like to hear****

Why would a school or organization enforce this?

If not or why do you think that there is not?

Does school or form make a difference?

Edit: Example in the class that i teach my students are instructed to answer "Yes teacher" in response to commands given by myself by the Certified school instructor.  However the respond to other commands given by a more experienced "instructors" would be "Yes sensei" or they (the instructor) may use another "yes ..."  in place in they wish.

Comment: Comments on why the down-vote would be useful...

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is either trivial to answer as [teach and instructor are synonimes](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/teacher) or is trying to pool opinions or just sounds like a bad request for a [motivation poster](https://rodschulhauser.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/leadership-vs-boss.jpeg) . My vote category is wrong, mouse slipped.

Comment: @Sardathrion Does that help

Comment: Given your edit, I don't see how this can be answered definitively.  It is clearly an organizational thing within your school.  It may even be a legal issue.  We simply can't give a single answer based on *all* of martial arts.

Comment: @TheWudangKid I don't see how you cant give a answer considering you answered in you comment  "It is clearly an organizational thing within your school." but thankyou for you input : )

Comment: sensei just the Japanese for teacher/instructor. It is the same meaning.

Comment: I don't really think your edit adds much clarity because what you mention is specific to what happens where you train.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We can't answer your question**

The particular distinction that you've provided differs between systems, languages, organizations, and sometimes individuals. Since you haven't specified your organization, we can't even address why they consider "instructor" and "teacher" differently.

More broadly, the reasoning may range from ceremonial titles (some styles have specific titles that depend upon rank, either absolute or relative) to legal (in some jurisdictions, titles are regulated. For an example outside of martial arts, you cannot advertise yourself as an engineer without being a graduate of an accredited program in some places) to personal (I had one teacher who refused to use the ceremonial title of "Master" because he was black and saw unfortunate implications in the word, and there's an entire can of worms in whether to call female black-belts "Mistress" in some styles) to linguistic (the question of whether titles are translated, and how they're translated, is contentious).

Comment: Karate & thank you for the answer this was what i was wondering in general terms.